# Why can't I get jquery ui sortable to have a "smooth" horizontal auto scroll?

Tags: css, jquery-ui-sortable, horizontal-scrolling

I have a web page [that uses jquery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) with connectwith to have a list of lists (think similar to [trello](http://www.trello.com)).  One issue is that i can't seem to get a smooth horizontal auto scroll when the number of columns exceeds the window width.  So when the horizontal scroll get enacted when I drag an item to the right I have to also drag a bit up or down to get the scroll bar to move to the right (instead of just doing it by dragging directly right without this extra fiddling).

Here is a [jsfiddle example of my code](http://goo.gl/to7tAM) that shows the behavior.   Try to take an item from the first column and put it on the last list to the right.

[image]

[image]

NOTE: you must make the windows not too wide to make sure that all 6 "columns" aren't visible to get the behavior.  Once you do this, if you see the horizontal scroll gets "choppy" after you get to the edge.

Is there anyway to get a smooth horizontal auto scrolling when using jquery ui sortable

Comment: There is no horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @Zash Saucier - what do you mean.  As i said in my question you have to make sure the width of the screen (or that section is not to wide)

Comment: I mean even if my window is 100px wide, the elements are wrapping to the next line, thus no scroll bar appears

Comment: that is weird as i don't see this (i am using chrome).  if you see in the css, i have this line:      white-space: nowrap; which keeps its from doing a wrap

Comment: Interesting, I'm in Chrome as well. Floating elements wrap as `white-space: nowrap` does not work for block elements but only for inline elements and text. [Changing them from floats to `display:inline`](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/d3qLx/5/) makes them have a horizontal bar. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ZachSaucier - I added a screenshot of what i see in my jsFiddle. as you can see the fifth and sixth rows don't wrap and instead will show up after dragging to the right and scrolling (im on a mac so horizontal scroll bar only shows up when i actually scroll which is hard to screenshot).  Do you see something different?

Comment: (`whitespace:nowrap` should have no effect on floating elements, I think you need `display:inline-block` instead) I would recommend using an overlay on either end to ease the horizontal scroll. Using a pluging like [jQuery Smooth Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#toc) would make it pretty easy, though you could create a custom one if you want. Essentially you'd only allow the smooth scroll if one of the elements is being dragged

Comment: @ZachSaucier -  Just to make sure i understand you correctly.  Is this a limitation of the default browser drag and srcrolling or an issue with jquery ui sortable?  I would have thought this would be a simpler way to get this expected behavior without additional plugins, etc . .

Comment: @leora Zach Saucier's recommendation is exactly what [I was recommending in my follow up to your comment.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177327/how-can-i-have-an-element-with-overflow-y-auto-but-still-allow-the-browser-to/21242815#comment32993527_21242815) Plugins exists that will solve this scroll issue ([#1 on my orig. comment](http://www.khazar.com/academics/portal/canada/2011spring/mart369/javascript/jmycarousel.htm)). There are lightweight solutions you could implement yourself ([#3 on my orig. comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188952/scroll-on-hover-click-for-speed)).

Comment: @leora It's a browser issue, you need to work around it as JSuar suggests

Comment: For proper fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/d3qLx/6/

Comment: @Mr. Alien - i see the same scrolling choppy issue in your fiddle

Comment: @leora Your fiddle was not proper as you were using floats, so I just fixed that, I didn't fixed your issue else would've answered as I didn't understood your question at first place :)

Comment: @Mr. Alien - I just took the css directly from the jquery sortable example page: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: @ZachSaucier - it looks like this other question is dealing with the same issue (although the problem vertically): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739419/jquery-sortable-and-automatic-scrolling

Comment: Do not use URL shorteners to work around deliberate quality filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Zach Saucier mentioned in the comments, your example doesn't trigger horizontal scrolling. Replacing `float: left` with `display: inline-block` does work as you describe, though.

To solve your problem, try adding the `scrollSensitivity: 100` to the list of options to the `sortable` call, e.g.:

```
$(function () {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    scrollSensitivity: 100
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Adjust value as needed. This is referred to [in the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-scrollSensitivity).

Comment: I wound up making scrollSensitivity:250 and that seems to work for me