# I can not drag items freely

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
       <th>Logo</th>
       <th>Artical</th>
       <th>News</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sortable">
       <td>something</td>
       <td class="ui-state-default">2014 news from our department</td>
       <td class="ui-state-default"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with this JavaScript code to allow the user to drag text from artical column to news column and vice versa

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable();
            $("#sortable").disableSelection();
        });
</script>
```

the problem: It's painful to drag and drop from column to other, I often fail when trying to drag the item over the column.. I should snipe to succeed! anyone face this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/ffz3cphg/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adjust the scrollSensitivity value?

For instance:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({scrollSensivity:300});
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802949/why-cant-i-get-jquery-ui-sortable-to-have-a-smooth-horizontal-auto-scroll).

Comment: You can try to use `{tolerance:"pointer"}`. Set a `min-width` for `td` elements should also help...